# In C, is node.next->prev the same as node->next->prev?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

Does the expression `node.next->prev` evaluate to the same thing as `node->next->prev`?

Comment: No, ”.” Is for structs while ”->” is for pointers.

Comment: Have you tried it?  In the scope of any given identifier "`node`", at most one of those will compile.

Comment: `foo->bar` is equivalent to `(*foo).bar`, so no.

Comment: @scholarhoopoe It can for example depend on whether there is a #define directive between these two expressions.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, at least one of `node.next->prev` and `node->next->prev` won't compile.

If `node` is declared as a pointer to a structure (say, `struct Node* node`), then you can't use the `.` operator on it because `.` can only be applied to honest-to-goodness `struct`s, not pointers to them. In that case, `node.next->prev` won't compile, while `node->next->prev` will. Conversely, if `node` is defined as an actual honest-to-goodness `struct` (say, `struct Node node`), then `node->next->prev` won't compile because `->` can only be applied to pointers, while `node.next->prev` will.

That being said, the *intent* behind these two pieces of code is the same. They both mean "go to some node, pick out its `next` field, then read the `prev` field of whatever node that is."